# construction of the minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to construct an $n\times n $ matrix over $\mathbb R$ having minimal polynomial $x^{n-1}$?
Sorry to say I failed to give any suitable approach  in this regard.

Comment: Consider an upper-triangular matrix with ones on the first super-diagonal, then the second, then the third, and see how this affects the minimal polynomial.

Comment: characteristic poly is coming as $x(x-1)(x-2)$ for a $3\times 3 $ matrix

Comment: It is not possible for $n=1$ (nor for $n=0$, for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a block diagonal matrix of an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix with minimal polynomial $X^{n-1}$ (for instance the companion matrix of this polynomial) and of a $1\times1$ matrix whose minimal polynomial is a divisor of$~X^{n-1}$. The latter divisor is necessarily $X$ if $n>1$, but if $n=1$ it cannot be done. There are no $1\times1$ matrices with minimal polynomial$~X^0=1$ (in fact the only such matrix is the $0\times0$ matrix).